# Is HortonWorks Sandbox VM preferred in production environment?

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform

The HortonWorks HDP, could be implemented in two ways:

1. Sandbox (VM)
2. Manual Installation.

I would like to understand, whether HDP SandBox, or the manual installation is preferred in the production environment. The choice could be made on obvious reasons like performance, but I would like to understand whether there are any other considerations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Hortonworks Sandbox allows to try out the features and functionality in Hadoop and its' ecosystem of projects. That's all.

If you want to go to production, you have three installation type:

- Automated with Ambari
- Manual
- Cloud with Cloudbreak

Regards,
Alain

Comment: I have marked this as answer, however I am still not sure why Microsoft supports Sandbox VM.

Answer (score 0):

1. performance. hadoop is about parallel processing. Can't do that with a single node.
2. storage. hadoop uses a distributed file system. With a single node your storage space is very limited.
3. redundancy. if this node dies, everything is gone. Normal hadoop configuration include a redundancy factor (of 3 by default) so that when some nodes or disks go down, all of the data is still reachable. Similarly with a standby namenode.

There are a few other points, but these are the main ones IMO.

Single node hadoop only makes sense for proof of concept, and experimentation. Not for providing production level value.

Comment: I am trying to understand whether production environment uses HDP SandBox or standalone HDP machines. HDP could be installed on one machine only and then using Ambari you can setup a multi-node cluster.  HDP (or Sandbox VM) need not be installed on all the machines.  I am more interested in understanding whether SandBox VM is used in production environment (single node or multi-node etc.).

Comment: Sandbox, as the name implies, is a play area. The goal is to help one to get acquainted with HDP's hadoop offering without needing to go through the burden of installing it, configuring it, and setting up multiple machines for it. Install on your laptop, start it up, and you're ready to roll (as in - play, experiment, etc). It is not intended to be used in production. In production, as you mention, one would use Ambari to install and configure the HDP libraries from scratch, according to specific needs and environment.

Comment: I have come to know that HDP SandBox is available on Windows Azure, which is a production environment. I understand that SandBox helps you to get quickly started on HDP, but if it is supported in production environment, what are factors that would help me to choose between Sandbox or a standalone HDP machine (Non-VM)?